# How to add a Mercurial repository(clone) of a remote IP address in Xcode, it says "Host unreachable"

Tags: xcode, mercurial

I am trying to add a repository(Clone) for my iPhone project which is of (hg) mercurial repository.
When I enter the project path(remote server) in the organizer to add a repository, it says "Host Unreachable".

But if I use source tree or take a clone from the terminal it works fine.
I found some solutions for SVN but not for HG type. (Using Xcode 4.4.1)

Can someone please help out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the same protocol in the terminal and in Xcode?

Comment: I am using "hg clone ssh://hg@xxx.xx.xx.xxx/Projectname" in terminal

Comment: @davids in xcode I use the same "IP address" mentioned above in organizer to add or clone a repository!

Comment: @trojanfoe i am not sure, I think its 'mercurial' as I see 'hg' in the ip:address.(so if its a 'hg' can't I clone/add repo from 'xcode')

Comment: but what protocol do you use in xcode?? SSH, Https or git?

Comment: Xcode doesn't support mercurial.  Why have you mentioned git in your question if you don't know what it is?

Comment: @trojanfoe oh! sorry for that.. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to the remote server in finder first. You should then be able to see it as a mounted device. Then try again in xCode